# My boolean variable is always False inside OnTriggerStay()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

This is very weird, and I can't figure it out!

I have a simple `boolean` variable.

```
public bool hitBoxIsOpen;
```

it is set to **false** in the Start().

For testing purposes, I made a `button-press` set it to **True**.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
    {
        hitBoxIsOpen = true;
        print("HitBox: " + hitBoxIsOpen);
    }
}
```

This does exactly what it is supposed to, and prints "True" afterwards.

Then I have:

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    print(hitBoxIsOpen);
}
```

No matter what or when, this block always prints **False**!

Why is this?

Comment: Are you entering the trigger before pressing the KeyCode.Alpha3 key ? If you Press that key and then Enter the trigger what it shows ? Is it still false ?

Comment: Where are you changing hitBoxIsOpen? If you never change it it will always be false. If you want to change it inside the OnTriggerStay you should set it there ( hitBoxIsOpen = true;). If you are changing it somewhere else I need to see entire code?

Answer (score 1):

If your object has `Rigidbody` and `Trigger` on `BoxCollider Component` is on, it works